# Finding the probability of winning on or before n trials?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, partitioning

I have two teams A and B, the probability that A wins  each hole is p, the probability that B wins each hole is q and the probability that neither wins is r. What is the probability of A winning on or before the n trials? The trials are independent and the game stops as soon as one team wins.

I calculated the probability of A winning is $p/(1-r)$ by partitioning.

I know the answer is :

$$p \frac{1-r^n}{1-r}$$

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probability that $A$ wins in the first trial is $p$. For $A$ to win on the second trial, none of the teams should win in the first one, and $A$ should win on the second, i.e. $rp$. Similarly, for $i$-th trial, we have $r^{i-1}p$. Summing each yields:
$$P(\text{A wins on or before n trials})=p(1+r+\dots+r^{n-1})=p\frac{1-r^n}{1-r}$$